# Electrical counterpart: Logical not

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra, circuits

I'm building a circuit where I must receive a signal from a logical not. More specifically, I'm looking for a real-life electrical circuit element/component that provides power/signal on the output when there is no power on the input terminal, and cuts the power off at the output terminals off when there is power at the input terminal. I can make the circuit in theory but I have never come across a real life version of the logical not. Does it exist? What is it called?

Comment: People have suggested using a relay, which may work for you, but you'll get a better answer if you provide more information. To start with, what voltage is your input and how much current can it supply? What voltage and current does your output need?

Comment: A [NOT gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverter_(logic_gate)) is as real-life as other logical gates

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if you need just signal, you can use also transistor - less power consumption, can work directly with IC:

[image]

https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/logic_4.html

Comment: thank you for your comment @petr. I was thinking this after some research but for now my main goal is to make it as fast and cheap as possible. when i get to the stage where i wanna make it more improved i.e. V2.0, i will use a transistor for automatic switching instead of manually switching it. especially when i implement ICs as well.

Answer (score 5):

A relay would be one way to use a small signal for on/off control of a larger power source. Of course the relay itself does not supply the power, it only makes or breaks the circuit.

**Form 1A relay** controls one circuit, normally open, closed when the coil is energized. That’s not quite what you want, because it is on-when-on.

**Form 1B relay** controls one circuit, but the contacts are normally closed, and they open (breaking the circuit) when the coil is energized. **This is the type you want for your logic invert function.**

**Form 1C relay** has both normally-open and normally-closed contacts, so if you can’t find a Form B relay but can find a Form C relay, that can work.

One thing to watch out for is driving the relay coil. Since it’s a magnetic coil, it has inductance, so there will be some back EMF voltage induced when switching it off. The cure is putting a reverse-biased diode across the coil, providing a discharge path for the back EMF and preventing damage to the driving circuit.

There are also other solid-state equivalents, based around transistors and FETs. But conceptually the relay is more straightforward to understand.

By the way, there is a whole field of programmable logic controllers (PLC) which are programmed by ladder logic, that is traditionally built around relays.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. I was thinking of relays but they do have the problem on on-when-on as you say. if there was some way to complement that it would be exactly what i need. I do want the normally open and to close it when receives a signal from the input (clsoe circuit on output when the input is open 0A). i say signal but it's more off and on. im wondering whether there exists a single component that does this or i must use nmoses and create my own little circuit to provide me this feature.

Comment: @nikola - As Mark explains use the normally closed contacts on the relay - they are closed when there is no power applied to the relay. Use those contacts to turn on the output.

Answer (score 2):

The electrical circuit element you are looking for is an electromagnetic relay.

Here's the schematic.

[image]

When the input is off, relay 'K1' is off and it's 'NC' contact enables the output.

Likewise, when the input is on, relay 'K1' is on and it's 'NC' contact disables the output.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment. i will use an electromagnetic relay to achieve this. @vu2nan

Comment: Anytime, nikola. Have fun!